# order of taking expectation and multiplication

Tags: calculus, probability

There are two decreasing functions of a random variable $v$, $A(v)$ and $B(v)$,  $f(v)$ is the pdf of v.

I'm wondering if $A(v)B(v)<1$ for any v, is it true that $\int A(v)f(v)dv\int B(v)f(v)dv<1$ ?
If not, is there any condition that makes this true?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Note that the covariance of two decreasing functions of a random variable is nonnegative. This means that
$$E[AB]-E[A]E[B]\geq 0$$
Hence
$$ E[A]E[B]\leq E[AB]\leq 1$$

Comment: Thank you Matt, is there a general theory about this?

Comment: @chen which part?

Comment: I mean, is there a theorem on the inequalities you wrote.

Comment: @chen there is a question on this site about the covariance of two increasing functions being positive. This is equivalent to the covariance of two decreasing functions being positive. I'd give you a link but I'm using my cell phone and it's hard to copy links.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll look for it myself!

Comment: @chen you're welcome..